# Nested curly braces with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-filter

I'm currently working on a project using [angular-translate](http://pascalprecht.github.io/angular-translate/). The goal for me is to create a translation map which allows a developer to change an object model without breaking the translation.

For example, say I have an order saved inside my scope:

```
$scope.order = {
    numberOfItems: 5,
    // ...
};
```

And a translation map with a property displaying the number of items:

```
var translationsEN = {
    itemsNumber: "{{numberOfitems}} item(s)",
    // ...
};

var translationsFR = {
    itemsNumber: "{{numberOfItems}} article(s)",
    // ...
};
```

With this map, I could easily do this:

```
{{'itemsNumber' | translate:order}}
```

But if a developer would like to change the name of the `numberOfItems` property, he will have to change the translation map too, which is pretty fastidious... So, I've changed my translation map for this:

```
var translationsEN = {
    itemsNumber: "{{number}} item(s)",
    // ...
};

var translationsFR = {
    itemsNumber: "{{number}} article(s)",
    // ...
};
```

Now, a developer just have to transmit a simple object with the necessary values, like this:

```
<span translate="order.misc.itemsNumber"
       translate-values="{ number:{{order.numberOfItems}} }">
</span>
```

But, as you can see, I'm no longer using filters but directives. I can't find any way to do something like this:

```
{{'order.misc.itemsNumber' | translate:'{ number:{{order.numberOfItems}} }'}}
```

This doesn't work either:

```
{{'order.misc.itemsNumber' | translate:'{ number:order.numberOfItems }'}}
```

Is there any solution allowing me to use filters or should I just use directives?

Answer (score 0):

Try without the quotes:

```
{{'order.misc.itemsNumber' | translate: {number: order.numberOfItems}}}
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it displays some blank values: " item(s)" and " article(s)"